# Creating a class which inherits from another class in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm trying to create a class called Musician which inherits from my class Person and then adds an instrument attribute. I know my Musician class is wrong, but I just wanted to know what the correct format is in Ruby. Here is all of my code:

```
class Person
  attr_reader :first_name, :last_name, :age
  def initialize (first_name, last_name, age)
    @first_name = first_name
    @last_name = last_name
    @age = age
  end
end

p = Person.new("Earl", "Rubens-Watts", 2)
p.first_name
p.last_name
p.age


class Musician < Person
  attr_reader :instrument
  def initialize (instrument)
    @instrument = instrument
  end
end

m = Musician.new("George", "Harrison", 58, "guitar")
m.first_name + " " + m.last_name + ": " + m.age.to_s
m.instrument
```

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want first_name, last_name and age to be available in Musician then you must include them in the initializer and take advantage of `super`. Something like:

```
class Musician < Person
  attr_reader :instrument

  def initialize(first_name, last_name, age, instrument)
    super(first_name, last_name, age)
    @instrument = instrument
  end
end
```

`super` calls the method with the same name inside of the parent class.

**UPDATE**

I will drive the point home. You would also use super in this totally made up situation:

```
class GuitarPlayer < Person
  attr_reader :instrument

  def initialize(first_name, last_name, age)
    super(first_name, last_name, age)
    @instrument = 'guitar'
  end
end
```

We haven't changed the arguments to initialize but we have extended the behavior.

Comment: Thanks Patrick. So you have to use super if you are creating a class which inherits three or more attributes from a parent class in Ruby?

Comment: You use super if you override a method from the parent class but you still want to access the behavior of the parent class from within the child class' method. It's not exclusive to `initialize`.

Answer (score 0):

That is the format for extending a class.

The problem is that you're calling the `Musician` initializer with more attributes than it accepts.

The error message you get states this pretty explicitly. When reporting or asking for help regarding an error, the error message you get should be shared so we don't have to guess or run your program.

You have at least options:

- Give `Musician` an `initialize` that takes all the params, grabs instrument, and passes the rest.
- Use Rails' Hash-based `initialize` (or roll your own, but you tagged it with rails).